# Getting array details and show the Contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

Here i fetched the data from address book.The below format i fetched into the contacts on my phone.

```
[
{
    "Firstname": "Kate",
    "Lastname": "Bell",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555) 564-8583"
},
{
    "Firstname": "john",
    "Lastname": "Bell",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555)564-8583"
},
{
    "Firstname": "anna",
    "Lastname": "naik",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555) 564-8583"
},
{
    "Firstname": "dec",
    "Lastname": "alex",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555)564-8583"
},
{
    "Firstname": "anna",
    "Lastname": "naik",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555) 564-8583"
},
{
    "Firstname": "dec",
    "LKateame": "alex",
    "mobileNumber": "(555)564-8583",
    "homeNumber": "(555) 564-8583"
}
```

]
here i get the Firstname data and displayed into the `UITableView` ,but the problem is when i tap the name on the `TableView` ,it will display to the anotherView.In the another View Contact name and respective numbers should be displayed.How can it's implemented .Can you please suggest me,thank you.

Comment: You can use segue for that, You can perform segue in DidSelect method of tableview cell and pass array object with prepareForSegue method to another view(destination viewcontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should create a class, Such as "People", to store the information and put them in an array.

then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   People *people = self.peopleArray[indexPath.row];

   UIViewController *newViewController = [UIViewController alloc] init]
   newViewController.people = people;

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
}
```

so, get what you want from the array in the new ViewController.